# call url from url id instead form

Tags: javascript, php

I have code which play google drive video. but it only play when i put url in browser form and click play. but i want to remove that form and directly play video when user visit url with google drive file id.

i want to play video by url like below

mydomain.com/index.php?id=0ByaRd0R0Qyatcmw2dVhQS0NDU0U

but i am not able to do that. can anyone help me please.

below is my php code

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg7Yh.png

my index.php code https://pastebin.com/kUGCGHk7

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include "curl_gd.php";

if($_POST['submit'] != ""){
$url = $_POST['url'];
$linkdown = Drive($url);
$file = '[{"type": "video/mp4", "label": "HD", "file":             "'.$linkdown.'"}]';
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="text" size="80" name="url"         value="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByaRd0R0Qyatcmw2dVhQS0NDU0U/view"/>
            <input type="submit" value="PLAY" name="submit" />
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your example site is : *mydomain.com/index.php?id=0ByaRd0R0Qyatcmw2dVhQS0NDU0U*

You just need to replace `$_POST` by `$_GET` then construct the full url

```
<?php
  error_reporting(0);
  include "curl_gd.php";

  if($_GET['id'] != ""){

    $id  = $_GET['id'];
    $url = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/" . $id . "/view/";

    $linkdown = Drive($url);
    $file = '[{"type": "video/mp4", "label": "HD", "file":"' .$linkdown. '"}]';
  }
?>
```

Comment: no i already tried this . but it just fill the url in form box. i have to manually click on play button to get output.    <form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" size="80" name="url" value="https://drive.google.com/file/d/<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>/view"/>
<input type="submit" id="btn" value="PLAY" name="submit" />
</form>

Comment: i want direct output without clicking play button in form.